# jupyter notebook export omits markdown

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

Given a jupyter notebook (here Test_Export.ipynb) with the following content:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "attachments": {},
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "This is markdown."
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "print('This is code.')"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.11.4"
  },
  "orig_nbformat": 4
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

I'd like to export the executed notebook without input code to asciidoc format. In order to do that, I use the offical docker image and execute:

`docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash -P -v ${PWD}:/home/jovyan/ jupyter/minimal-notebook:notebook-6.5.4 -c "jupyter nbconvert --execute --to asciidoc --no-input Test_Export.ipynb"`

The result looks as follows:

```
----
This is code.
----
```

Somehow any markdown area is completely omitted which is the case for *base-notebook* image and *minimal-notebook* one. Using *datascience-notebook* image, the markdown sections are correctly exported to the asciidoc file.

Why is that?

Comment: If everything is the same except the docker images, then my guess would be the version of `nbconvert` in two of the images is different and has an issue. You listed the versions in all those and compared? I couldn't find any matching your description [on the nbconvert issues page](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues) but I may not be searching with the correct terms to turn it up.

Comment: Indeed the versions differ! For the same tags the minimal and base image have nbconvert version 7.6.0 and datascience only 7.5.0. I'll try to find a minimal version that also uses 7.5.0 in order to verify if nbconvert is the problem here.

Comment: The one concern I have is that I wish we could find where the issue has been reported. Because it will continue for longer if it isn't already filed and being handled.

Comment: Okay, I've submitted a new issue on github: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by *Wayne* in the comments, the problem refers to the version of  `nbconvert`. It seems that versions above 7.5.0 have this problem, so I switched to the following image:

```
jupyter/minimal-notebook:9e3ab9075a5e
```

This one contains version 7.4.0 and exports the notebook to asciidoc format successfully.

Answer (score 0):

To omit the input code, simply do the following.

```bash
jupyter nbconvert yourNotebook.ipynb --no-input
```

What is the purpose of your docker container here? It seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: No, it is relevant in my case! I have to use a docker image due to a CI/CD pipeline that is going to build the mentioned export. Thus, I need that environment!